# Can I export React Hook function to UI component, and trigger it?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I have a custom Hook, which looks like below

```
export default () => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return { isActive, setIsActive }
}
```

Then in component A

```
export default () => {
  const { setIsActive } = useCustomHook();
  const clickHandler = () => {
    setIsActive(true);
  }
  return <button onChange={clickHandler}/>
}
```

In component B

```
export default () => {
  const { isActive } = useCustomHook();
  
  return isActive ? 'It is active' : 'It is NOT active';
}
```

When I click the button in Component A, I am expecting Component B changes state,
however, it doesn't work, so that makes me wonder if this is wrong way to reuse custom Hook.

Comment: If you call the hook in two separate files won't give you your expected results. It is just as having 2 separate instances of that hook that have nothing to do with each other. Either persist state or merge component A and B together.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from the signature, whenever you call `useCustomHook`, new state is created for specific component, which means that hook doesn't share state when called from multiple components.

You have several options:

**Lift your shared state** above components that use that state

```
const Parent = () => {
  const { isActive, setIsActive } = useCustomHook();
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <ComponentA active={isActive} setActive={setIsActive} />
      <ComponentB active={isActive} setActive={setIsActive} />
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

**Use state management** like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/), [Mobx](https://mobx-react.js.org/recipes-context) or something else for sharing your state within components without need of lifting your state and passing it through all the props.

You could also use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which doesn't require any additional packages to be installed and enables you to share state within specific parent component, but also doesn't require passing through all the props.